# Can't block access to a file using htaccess

Tags: json, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to block a file `config.json` from access, so I put `.htaccess` file like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule config.json - [F]
```

In directory `~/projects/bush` but when I access `localhost/projects/bush/config.json` I still see the content of the file, what wrongs here?

Comment: Do .htaccess files work otherwise in other contexts?  At the server level, `AllowOverride` must be set to enable them at the directory level...

Comment: It doesn't actually affect your use case, but the `.` should be escaped as `config\.json` - otherwise it matches any character so if you had a valid file `configxjson` that would also be blocked by your rule.  Just good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the web server's configuration (`httpd.conf`) for `AllowOverride None` as it disables reading of .htaccess for the directories it applies to. It is often done to increase performance.

Comment: Yes, that was it, found it before I see the answer, I've None in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` and change it to `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
RewriteRule ^/?config\.json$ - [F,L]
```

This probably will work.